# How to download files using Springboot @RestController via ajax

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an Springboot rest controller to download a file. I am trying to access the endpoint using the browser and able to see the response in the xhr.response. However, i want to force the file download which i am not able to achieve.

The code is as follows :
Rest based endpoint (Springboot):

```
    @GetMapping(value = "download/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, consumes = "*/*")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@PathVariable("id") Long contractId) {

    Contract contract;
    contract = this.contractRepository.findOne(contractId);
    System.out.println(contract.getPath()); // test
    InputStreamResource resource    = null;
    HttpHeaders         respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    if (contract != null) {

        try {
            File            file            = new File(contract.getPath());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            resource = new InputStreamResource(fileInputStream);
            System.out.println(resource.exists());//test

            respHeaders.add("Content-Type", URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(fileInputStream));
            respHeaders.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            respHeaders.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            respHeaders.add("Expires", "0");
            respHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());
            respHeaders.add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Binary");
            respHeaders.setContentLength(file.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(
            this.companyService.downloadContract(contractId),
            respHeaders,
            HttpStatus.OK
    );


}
```

My xhr request is as follows

```js
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", http.getHRTargetURL() + "download/" + id, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", http.getToken());
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
 
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.response != "0") {
         console.log(xhr)
         console.log("Downloaded file");
     } else {
        console.log("error downloading document")
     }
  }
xhr.send();
```

I am able to get the response from the endpoint . I can see the file contents in the xhr response on the browser
[image]

My problem is how can I force this response to popup file save wizard on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.response != "0") {
         console.log(xhr)
        var windowUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var url = windowUrl.createObjectURL(xhr);
        anchor.prop('href', url);
        anchor.prop('download', "filename");
        anchor.get(0).click();
        windowUrl.revokeObjectURL(url);
         console.log("Downloaded file");
     } else {
        console.log("error downloading document")
     }
  }
xhr.send();
```

Comment: there is a typo . You should change windowUrl to window.URL

Answer (score 1):

Well as I figured out that problem was with the frontend and had nothing to do with backend as Springboot was sending the proper response back.

Building on the answer provided by Dinesh above i modified my answer as follows

```
download(id, name){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", http.getHRTargetURL() + "download/" + id, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", http.getToken());
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.responseType       = "blob";

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style    = "display: none";
        var url    = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "octet/stream"}));
        a.href     = url;
        a.download = name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      } else {
        console.log("error downloading document")
      }
    }
    xhr.send();

  }
```